# How to set and get hidden field in asp.net mvc 3 or 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET.NVC MVC 4.

How can I set a value for the hidden field in asp.net mvc 3 or 4?

In the razor View I have written:

```
 @Html.Hidden("HProjectTypeId", Model.ProductTypeId);
```

But in the controller, I'm getting the null value.

Comment: The name of your field must match exactly with the name of the parameter in the action, or property on your model. Case sensitivity will matter as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the controller action that you are submitting the form to takes a `HProjectTypeId` parameter, then this parameter will be passed a correct value from the hidden field:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(int hProjectTypeId)
{
    // hProjectTypeId will contain the value of the hidden field here

    ...
}
```

This also works with models as well. Assuming you have the following model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int HProjectTypeId { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

and a controller action taking this view model as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    // model.HProjectTypeId will contain the value of the hidden field here
    ...
}
```

you will be able to read the value of the hidden field that was POSTed to the server.

Comment: using formcollection how to retrieve, here is my code. var hiddenId = _collection["HProjectTypeId"];This is also getting null

Comment: You should not use FormCollection - you should use strongly typed view models. But if for some reason you want to go against good practices and still use FormCollection then `collection["HProjectTypeId"]` should give you the desired result. If it doesn't this means that the problem is somewhere else. Maybe you didn't POST the form correctly? Maybe you used some AJAX and forgot to include this parameter? I cannot be guessing, there could be lots of reasons why your code doesn't work (and since you haven't shown your code I cannot really tell you why)...

Comment: ... but assuming you have an HTML `<form>` containing this hidden field and a standard submit button, when the form is submitted to the controller action you should be able to retrieve the value of the hidden field using the `HProjectTypeId` parameter because that's how your hidden field is named.

Answer (score 0):

to set the value of hidden filed you can try this one

```
<input id="hmsgs-to-ids" type="hidden" value="@(Model != null ? Model.ToIds : "")" />
```

as value give the models properties